# Openldap Password change at first login

Tags: linux, centos6, openldap, password-policy

I have implemented openldap in centos 6, I want to push password change policy at first login. Which pwdPolicy ObjectClass and Attributes can accomplish this task ?

```
    # MyOrgPPolicy, Policies, eostest.com
    dn: cn=MyOrgPPolicy,ou=Policies,dc=eostest,dc=com
    cn: MyOrgPPolicy
    pwdInHistory: 4
    pwdMinLength: 9
    pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
    objectClass: pwdPolicy
    objectClass: device
    objectClass: top
    objectClass: pwdPolicyChecker
    pwdMustChange: TRUE
    pwdMaxFailure: 3
    pwdCheckQuality: 1
    pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
    pwdAttribute: userPassword
    pwdLockout: TRUE
    pwdSafeModify: FALSE
    pwdExpireWarning: 1
    pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 5
    pwdLockoutDuration: 60
    pwdMaxAge: 2592000
    pwdMinAge: 300
    pwdCheckModule: pwcheck.la
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Apache Directory Studio you can see a Attribute called **passwordMustChange**

> When on, this attribute requires users to change their passwords when
>   they first login to the directory or after the password is reset by
>   the Directory Manager. The user is required to change their password
>   even if user-defined passwords are disabled. If this attribute is set
>   to off, passwords assigned by the Directory Manager should not follow
>   any obvious convention and should be difficult to discover. This
>   attribute is off by default.

Which I found [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/CDS/ag/8.0/User_Account_Management-Managing_the_Password_Policy.html) .

Comment: Is also passwordChange set on ?

Comment: I have used phpldapadmin and value of pwdMustChange: TRUE is set.
But new users are not asked to change the password at first login or when I change password from phpldapadmin.

If I remove pwdMustChange and add passwordMustChange to my policy, I get error

    ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17)
    additional info: passwordMustChange: attribute type undefined

I have also set pwdLockout: TRUE, pwdReset: TRUE & pwdMaxFailure: 3, if user attempts wrong password 3 times, account gets locked. After I reset the password, user is able to use new pass without system prompting for change.

Comment: pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE is also set

Comment: Then i don't know. You should add this information for others to your question!

Comment: I have edited my question and added my policy info

Comment: If you add a new user, and this user will log in the first time, he isn't forced to change his password? Is this right? And you tested it everytime with a new created user?

Comment: yes I create new user to test every time, new user is logged in without any prompt from system. I suspect PAM config at client side. Any suggestions ?